Locally compact locally connected space is paracompact iff each component is $\sigma$-compact
I would like to prove : given a locally compact locally connected topological space $X$, then $X$ is paracompact if and only if each connected component is $\sigma$-compact.
I thought I had something for the converse, but maybe not : each connected component is closed, then it is locally compact as a closed subset of $X$.

Does your definition of local compactness include $T_2$?

It does, let's stay with the definition from Wikipedia.

This can be found in Dugundji's Topology (theorem 7.3), and even Bredon's Topology and geometry (theorem 12.11)

BTW: Wikipedia does not require that locally compact spaces are $T_2$.

Sorry; in French, it does.

Yes, this is true, at least if the space is $T_2$, hence regular.
"$\Leftarrow$":
By the prerequisite, each component is Lindelöf, hence paracompact.
Moreover, the connected components form a clopen partition of the space, hence it is paracompact.
"$\Rightarrow$" is a little bit more complicated.
We need an additional property:
A space is called strongly paracompact, if it is $T_2$ and every open cover has a star-finite open refinement, see Engelking, General topology, p. 326.  
Let $C$ be a connected component of $X$. Since $C$ is closed, it is locally compact and paracompact, hence strongly paracompact (Engelking, Exercise 5.3.G.(a)). Since $C$ is connected, it is Lindelöf (Engelking, Ex. 6.1.E.). Hence, local compactness implies that C is $\sigma$-compact (Engelking, 3.8.C.(b)).
Note that for "$\Rightarrow$" we haven't used that $X$ is locally connected, and for "$\Leftarrow$" only the weaker condition, that all components are open.
Remark:
Without $T_2$, at least "$\Leftarrow$" does not hold according to $\pi$-base.

I don't get why the fact that there is a clopen partition of paracompact components implies $X$ is paracompact.

Plus, why do you use the Lindelöf property ? Isn't a closed subset of $X$ automatically paracompact ?

@Loulou: a sum of paracompact spaces is paracompact, see for instance Engelking, Theorem 5.1.30 for reference, although the proof is almost straightforward.

@Loulou: about your second question: which part of the proof does it refer to: "$\Rightarrow$"  or "$\Leftarrow$"?

The converse. We've established that each connected component is closed. Then it is paracompact, as a closed subset of a paracompact, isn't it ?

@Loulou: yes. But for $\sigma$-compactness we need more, namely that it is Lindelöf.

I'll try again. Each connected component $A$ is open because $X$ is locally connected. Then $A$ is closed, then $A$ is locally compact (as a closed subspace of a locally compact). Then $A$ is paracompact (because locally compact $+$ $\sigma$-compact $\implies$ paracompact). So using all my hypotheses, I avoid using the Lindelöf property, don't you agree?

@Loulou: you are arguing this direction "⇐", don't you? Yes, of course, just σ-compact and regular, T2 implies paracompact. But the standard proof for this is: σ-compact ⇒ Lindelöf ⇒ paracompact. Of course, it's fine, if you just handle this in one step.

BTW: this was the reason why I first asked you which direction you refer to. Of course, the arguments in "$\Leftarrow$" are more or less clear (and can avoid Lindelöfness, if you prefer). But for "$\Rightarrow$" the above proof definitely needs Lindelöf.

@Loulou: Another remark, which might be helpful for you: here and in your question, you seem to argue that components are closed, since they are open in a locally connected space. But components are always closed.

The converse is the implication "⇐". Thank you for the last remark! I'm a little rusty...
